# Delphi Rio 10.3.2 - unable to register a simple 32-bit ActiveX server

Tags: delphi

I was trying out writing a simple 32-bit ActiveX DLL in Delphi Rio 10.3.2/Windows 10, compile it and register it from IDE (32bit IDE should not have any problem with 32 bit DLL, right?). Always getting "failed to register" error.

When I create a new File > New > Windows > ActiveX Library, save the project locally with some meaningful name, compile and register it through IDE, it **works**. I then, add file > new > Individual files > COM Object and add a simple method to the interface and implement it and then try to compile, it compiles fine but **fails** when registering through IDE (or through command prompt).

Generated _TLB.pas code:

```
uses Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Win.StdVCL, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.OleServer, Winapi.ActiveX;

// *********************************************************************//
// GUIDS declared in the TypeLibrary. Following prefixes are used:
//   Type Libraries     : LIBID_xxxx
//   CoClasses          : CLASS_xxxx
//   DISPInterfaces     : DIID_xxxx
//   Non-DISP interfaces: IID_xxxx
// *********************************************************************//
const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  ActiveXLibTestMajorVersion = 1;
  ActiveXLibTestMinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_ActiveXLibTest: TGUID = '{892B49FC-855C-49DD-B983-62A58D57D29D}';

  IID_IMyTest: TGUID = '{78590964-7C52-4E1D-90F6-75F5FF3993C7}';
  CLASS_MyTest: TGUID = '{18281AC8-A37F-4285-B805-CBC53932E16A}';
type

// *********************************************************************//
// Forward declaration of types defined in TypeLibrary
// *********************************************************************//
  IMyTest = interface;

// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of CoClasses defined in Type Library
// (NOTE: Here we map each CoClass to its Default Interface)
// *********************************************************************//
  MyTest = IMyTest;


// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IMyTest
// Flags:     (0)
// GUID:      {78590964-7C52-4E1D-90F6-75F5FF3993C7}
// *********************************************************************//
  IMyTest = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{78590964-7C52-4E1D-90F6-75F5FF3993C7}']
    function GetName: WideString; stdcall;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// The Class CoMyTest provides a Create and CreateRemote method to
// create instances of the default interface IMyTest exposed by
// the CoClass MyTest. The functions are intended to be used by
// clients wishing to automate the CoClass objects exposed by the
// server of this typelibrary.
// *********************************************************************//
  CoMyTest = class
    class function Create: IMyTest;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IMyTest;
  end;

implementation

uses System.Win.ComObj;

class function CoMyTest.Create: IMyTest;
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_MyTest) as IMyTest;
end;

class function CoMyTest.CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IMyTest;
begin
  Result := CreateRemoteComObject(MachineName, CLASS_MyTest) as IMyTest;
end;
```

here is the implementation:
    unit Main;

```
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  Windows, ActiveX, Classes, ComObj, StdVcl, ActiveXLibTest_TLB;

type

  TMyTest = class(TComObject, IMyTest)
  protected
    function GetName: WideString; stdcall;
  end;

implementation

uses ComServ;

function TMyTest.GetName: WideString;
begin
  Result := 'Test';
end;

initialization
  TComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TMyTest, Class_MyTest,
    'MyTest', '', ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

Comment: Have you tried using the source of TRegSvr to try registering the sever in code and seeing why it fails?

Comment: You need admin rights to register a COM server. Does the process have these rights?

Comment: I could register from command prompt running as an administrator. Thank you, all for your help.